# Grabbing data from table does not produce any result

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make the script work to grab a row of data from a table using what I have search in the internet. This script produce no output and no errors. Any help will do. Thak you.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"}
url = "https://bscscan.com/token/generic-tokentxns2?m=normal&contractAddress=0x0D0b63b32595957ae58D4dD60aa5409E79A5Aa96&a=0x81e0ef68e103ee65002d3cf766240ed1c070334d&sid=87aaaf5bf5aad80385b57f5f3fa2aa3a&p=1"

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url,headers=headers, timeout=5)
soupblockdetails = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for row in soupblockdetails.select("tr:has(td)")[:3]:
    item1 = row.find_all("td")[0].text[0:].strip()
    item2 = row.find_all("td")[1].text[0:].strip()
    item3 = row.find_all("td")[2].text[0:].strip()
    item4 = row.find_all("td")[1].a.get('href').split('a=')[-1]
    print ("{:<2} {:<43}   {:>25} {}".format(item1, item2, item3, item4))
```

Current Output:

```
no display
```

Intended Output:

```
0xb07b68f72f0b58e8cfb8c8e896736f49b13775ebda25301475d24554a601ff97   115 days 12 hrs ago   Yooshiba Inu: Deployer   KIPS: Locked Wallet  1,870.82
```

Comment: You can check table details by it's class: `class="table table-md-text-normal table-hover mb-4"`

Comment: tried this code `data = soupblockdetails.find("table",{"class":"table table-md-text-normal table-hover mb-4"})` but still does not work

Comment: Main issue here the table is embedded in an `iframe` thats `src` is generated dynamically by `JavaScript` - One option is to use  `Selenium` navigating to rendered `iframe` and grab the table.

Comment: @HedgeHog, i will make an edit to the url. Perhaps this can work. I will be happy if you can help out.

Comment: The issue with these new url referencing the `iframe` is the `sid` take a look at the `selenium` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### What happens?

Main issue here the `table` is embedded in an `iframe` thats `src` is generated dynamically by `JavaScript`

###### How to fix?

One option is to use `Selenium` navigating to rendered `iframe` and grab the `table`:

```
...
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to.frame('tokentxnsiframe')

soupblockdetails = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

for row in soupblockdetails.select("tr:has(td)")[:3]:
    print(f"{' '.join(row.stripped_strings)}\t{row.a.get('href').split('/')[-1]}")
...
```

##### Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://bscscan.com/token/0x0D0b63b32595957ae58D4dD60aa5409E79A5Aa96?a=0x81e0ef68e103ee65002d3cf766240ed1c070334d'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to.frame('tokentxnsiframe')

soupblockdetails = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

for row in soupblockdetails.select("tr:has(td)")[:3]:
    print(f"{' '.join(row.stripped_strings)}\t{row.a.get('href').split('/')[-1]}")
```

##### Output

```
0xb07b68f72f0b58e8cfb8c8e896736f49b13775ebda25301475d24554a601ff97 0x129fa7e8 2021-12-09 17:23:58 115 days 14 hrs ago Yooshiba Inu: Deployer IN KIPS: Locked Wallet 1,870.828693386970691791    0xb07b68f72f0b58e8cfb8c8e896736f49b13775ebda25301475d24554a601ff97
```